# Return latest insert id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, last-insert-id

I can't get latest insert id. This is my php code:

```
$query='INSERT INTO candidates (company_id, name, surname, address1, address2, city, county, postcode, cv, skills, distance) VALUES (10254, \'name\', \'surname\', \'1st Floor\', \'Street\', \'City\', \'County\', \'postcode\', \'0\', \'#6#,#3#,#2#,#1#,\', 25)';
$sql = mysql_query($query, $jobboard) or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM candidates AS ID',$jobboard);
```

When I put query `'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM candidates'` straight in MySQL in return I get as many record as I have in this table, all values are 0. For example right now I have 5 records, id are 2,3,4,5,6 (I removed 1st), I get this table:
LAST_INSERT_ID()
0
0
0
0
0

How can I get latest insert record ID? BTW 1 only column is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which is `id`.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, use mysqli_* or PDO (yo ucan easily retreive the last insert id with pdo by calling $db->lastinsertid() )

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` works for the current connection only, so what you see when pasting the code into your mySQL console is by design.

To find out why it doesn't work in PHP, you should add some error checking as shown in the manual... and what @Yazmat says of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

That all

[Documentation on mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `mysql_insert_id()` function to get the last ID like this:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

On that note, you also want to move to newer, shinier, safer [PHP PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) - all the benefits of the old depreciated mysql_* functions without the headaches and STDs :)

Answer (score 1):

Just by using `mysql_insert_id();` you can get the lase inserted id in databse.In you case you can use like this:

```
$query='INSERT INTO candidates (company_id, name, surname, address1, address2, city, county, postcode, cv, skills, distance) VALUES (10254, \'name\', \'surname\', \'1st Floor\', \'Street\', \'City\', \'County\', \'postcode\', \'0\', \'#6#,#3#,#2#,#1#,\', 25)';
$sql = mysql_query($query, $jobboard) or die(mysql_error());
$last_id=mysql_insert_id();//get last inserted id.
```